# Cumulative distribution function of correlated variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

this is a very general question
Suppose i have that $$cor(X,Y)=\rho >0$$
I am trying to estimate $$p(X<2Y)$$ using either conditional distribution of X, joint distribution of X,Y ...
I just really dont know which one you are meant to use in that case.

Answer (score -1):

There is more than one way to do it.  If you have the joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ then you perform a double integral over only the portion of the domain that satisfies $X < 2Y$.

I don't see a way to use correlation without knowledge of the distribution and its domain.